# I can't get the jquery plugin autoNumeric to work

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to jquery but learning. I pulled in jquery at the top of the program and added the autoNumeric plugin near the end of the head section.

```
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

...
    #numeric {
    text-align:right;
    }
...

```
<script src="jquery/autoNumeric-master/autoNumeric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> $("#numeric").autoNumeric('init'); </script>
<script> alert("just loaded and inited autonumeric"); </script> 
</head>
```

.....

```
<input id="numeric" class="input" name="Labor" type="text" size="20" maxlength="10" />
```

I have another jquery plugin working for pagination.

It has to be something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats the problem which you are facing?

Comment: Nothing happens. It is not reformatting the numeric data I type in.

Comment: Install firebug in FireFox and see if you don't get any javascript errors. THe usual culprit is the version of JQuery you are using or that the id you are referring to does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#numeric").autoNumeric('init');
      }); 
     </script>
```

instead of (replacing your original with the above)

```
<script> $("#numeric").autoNumeric('init'); </script>
```